# How to write the context of a FileStream to my ASP.net HTTP Response?

Tags: asp.net, download, filestream

Suppose that I want my ASP.net web server to open a file and then send it to the browser.

First, I write this:

```
FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"\\myshare\myfile.zip");
FileStream fileStream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

What comes next?

I would think something along the lines of `Response.Write(...`, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: It appears that Davide's answer and riffnl's answers both work.  Is there a case to be made that one solution is superior to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to send files is using the content-disposition header before you send the actual raw data

for instance:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/jpeg";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.WriteFile(path);
Response.End();
```

where fileName is just the filename (with extension)
and path is the full path to the file

Answer (score 5):

straight from MSDN:

[HttpResponse.BinaryWrite Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.binarywrite.aspx)

```
 FileStream MyFileStream;
 long FileSize;

 MyFileStream = new FileStream("sometext.txt", FileMode.Open);
 FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;

 byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize];
 MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)FileSize);
 MyFileStream.Close();

 Response.Write("<b>File Contents: </b>");
 Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

**Edit:** of course there are also many other methods, like streaming which allows you to never allocate the byte[] buffer all at once on the web server. This was just a starting point...